# I cannot get grid-template-columns to work in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-grid

I am having problems making grid-template-columns work in IE.
The result that I am getting is all in the first 100px column.

this is the basic html structure

```
<div class="bdm_grid">
  <img>
  <div>content</div>
  <div>content</div>
</div>
```

here is the css

```
.bdm_grid {
  display: -ms-grid !important;
  display: grid !important;
}
.bdm004 .bdm_grid{
-ms-grid-columns: 100px 1fr 150px;
    grid-template-columns: 100px auto 150px
 }
```

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Are you using IIS? Are any CSS properties working (such as font, color)? Is it working on other browsers?

Comment: @SoConfused Everything is working properly except the grid.  Everything, including the grid layout, works in all other browsers.  The site is on hubspot.

Comment: Just forget about IE and its support...not important.

Comment: I would love to think that way, but that is not an option.

Comment: I guess there is no fix?

Answer (score 0):

I've added the code into w3schools (jsfiddle doesn't support IE), and have run https://autoprefixer.github.io/ against the basic CSS to get https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FWFA9DG2F2RN

The  tag should be inside a div - you can see it now working on Chrome, but the CSS still doesn't work on IE and  I can't see why.